# Segmentation fault for the below program

Tags: c++, mergesort

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int inversions = 0;  

using namespace std;

void merge(int arr[], int start, int mid, int end){
    //      int    
}

void merge_sort(int arr[], int start, int end){

    int mid = 0;
    while(start < end)
    {       
        mid = end + (end - start)/2;
        merge_sort(arr, start, mid);
        merge_sort(arr, mid + 1, end);
        merge(arr, start, mid, end);
    }
}

int main(){

    int arr[6] = {233,5,1,33,66};
    merge_sort(arr, 0, 5);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to implement merge sort and find the number of inversions, but I am getting an error which says seg fault. The program is not complete yet. Can someone suggest what is wrong with the program that I have. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code, with a debugger?

Comment: I am sorry for this, relatively new to programming. Used GDB but I am not able to understand whats wrong

Comment: Are you sure about this: `mid = end + (end - start)/2;`

Comment: @Phaneeth As I mentioned - step through your code, line by line, while observing the values of the variables, to see where the code starts doing something you didn't expect.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good debugger. No one is going to compile and run this and tell you what is wrong. What have you done to solve this?

Comment: It is entering the function merge_sort and the next thing that pops is the seg fault in gdb. Do you have any suggestions

Comment: In the code shown I see nothing that could seg fault. My guess is it is in your merge function when mutating the array

Comment: @Phaneeth You're jumping over too much of code. Step through each line.

Answer (score 1):

The expression in this statement

```
mid = end + (end - start)/2;
```

is wrong.

You should write

```
mid = ( end + start)/2;
```